# Loading objects based on URL parameters in Magento

Tags: magento, parameter-passing, magento-1.5

I am having trouble creating a custom module for my Magento store.

I have successfully added a route (/landing), and created/layout files that display template content within my base layout. I now need to move beyond that a bit.

I want to be able to load a parameter from a URL, grab an object based on that parameter, and display things based on the contents of my object.

Example: User browsers to domain.com/landing/cool/. This (hopefully) would call the landing controller. Controller would somehow be able to pull the 'cool' parameter, and pull a landing object associated with cool. Then, my template can get that object and display its elements.

I know there are a lot of bits there, but I have been cracking my head on this for a while and getting nowhere. Magento has to do this for all its categories, items, etc. Does anyone out there know how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do domain.com/landing/[controller]/cool/[key]/[value], you can do $this->getRequest()->getParam('[key]') to get the value of [value].  You can then set the template based on that, but I think that's a different question.  Let me know if you're still confused.

Comment: I am definitely still confused :) Ideally, it would be  domain.com/landing/[variable] (cool was my example variable). How do I configure the magento to do this?

Comment: I edited my response because I mistyped it before.  In the current example you would get your request in coolAction() of LandingController.

Comment: If you must use that url format, I would make a server redirect from /landing/* to /landing/action/key/*.

Comment: Wow, completely out of it today.  It needs to be in the format  domain.com/frontname/controller/action/key/value. My bad.

Comment: Aha! that seems to be a large part of what I needed. I assume magento redirects cant do this, but I can just stick my own redirect in htaccess

Answer (score 2):

The following explanations assume that you've defined your frontname the usual way:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Landing>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Landing>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <landing>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompany_Landing</module>
                    <frontName>landing</frontName>
                </args>
            </landing>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

In this scenario the Magento Standard Router would map the URL `landing/cool` to

```
Mycompany_Landing_CoolController::indexAction()
```

This is because the Magento Standard Router handles URLs using a `frontname/controller/action` pattern and in your case it knows that

- the frontname is `landing`, which is mapped to the `Mycompany_Landing` module
- the controller name is `cool`, which will be transformed to `CoolController`
- the action name is missing, which will result in using `indexAction` by default

But you want `cool` to be a **parameter**, not a controller.

I guess the reasoning behind this is that you want to have multiple landing zones besides `landing/cool`, like `landing/awesome`, `landing/insane` and so on. And this would mean you'd have to setup multiple controllers, one for each different landing zone.

A possible solution to avoid multiple controllers in this case would be to implement your *own* router.

#### Implementing your own router

To implement your own router, you need to hook into the `controller_front_init_routers` event, e.g. by extending your `app/code/local/Mycompany/Landing/etc/config.xml` like this:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <landing>
                        <class>Mycompany_Landing_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>controllerFrontInitRouters</method>
                    </landing>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Next create a proper `app/code/local/Mycompany/Landing/Controller/Router.php` file:

```
class Mycompany_Landing_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Add own router to Magento router chain
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $oObserver
     */

    public function controllerFrontInitRouters($oObserver)
    {
        // Add this router to the current router chain
        $oObserver
            ->getEvent()
            ->getFront()
            ->addRouter('landing', $this);
    }

    /**
     * Match routes for the landing module
     *
     * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Http $oRequest
     * @return bool
     */

    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $oRequest)
    {

        $sPathInfo = trim($oRequest->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $aPathInfo = explode('/', $sPathInfo);

        // Cancel if the route request is for some other module
        if ($aPathInfo[0] != 'landing') {
            return false;
        }

        // Cancel if it's not a valid landing zone
        if (!in_array($aPathInfo[1], array('cool'))) {
            return false;
        }

        // Rewrite the request object
        $oRequest
            ->setModuleName('landing')
            ->setControllerName('index')
            ->setActionName('index')
            ->setParam('zone', $aPathInfo[1])
            ->setAlias(
                'landing_router_rewrite',
                true
            );

        // Tell Magento that this router can match the request
        return true;

    }

}
```

The `controllerFrontInitRouters()` method of the file above takes care that your own router will be merged into the Magento router chain so that it looks like this:

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
Mage_Cms_Controller_Router
Mycompany_Landing_Controller_Router
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Default
```

Magento will loop this chain in the given order when dispatching. That means, a custom router like yours will always be called at 4th position at the earliest. Your router will only be called, if none of the previous three routers could already match the route request.

When the `match()` method of the file is called and detects a valid route (currently `landing/cool` only), it will change the request object, so that `Mycompany_Landing_IndexController::indexAction()` will be dispatched, having a parameter `zone` with the value `cool`.

Note that this `match()` is oversimplified. It doesn't contain sanitizing, etc. Don't forget to fix this^^

Finally create a `app/code/local/Mycompany/Landing/controllers/IndexController.php` file:

```
class Mycompany_Landing_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

        if (!$this->getRequest()->getAlias('landing_router_rewrite')) {
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
            return;
        }

        $sZone = $this->getRequest()->getParam('zone');

        die(__METHOD__ . ' called with zone = ' . $sZone);

    }

}
```

The first `if` block of the `indexAction` cancels the action, if there's no `landing_route_rewrite` alias set in the request object (see `setAlias()` in your router's `match()` method).

This is done because a user otherwise could also reach this `indexAction()` by using other URLs like `landing`, `landing/index`, `landig/index/index`, `landing/index/index/zone/cool`, and so on.

I guess you don't want to have such other URLs been SEO ranked, nor to implement validation and sanitizing twice, but if you don't need it, just remove that `if` block.

Now you can extend the `indexAction()` to do whatever you like to do with your landing zones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into it a bit more here in a moment, but right now the only thing that's coming to mind is exploding on '/' to grab them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it through Javascript for one of my projects:

```
function populateSelect(url, element, target) {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById(element);
    var elementValue = selectedValue.options[selectedValue.selectedIndex].value;

    pathArray = url.split( '/' );
    pathArray.shift();
    pathArray.shift();
    pathArray.splice(5,0, element);
    pathArray.splice(6,0, elementValue);
    url = pathArray.join("/");
    url = 'http://' + url;

    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method:    "POST",
        onSuccess:
            function(transport) {
                var json    = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
                var options = '';
                $(target).descendants().each(Element.remove);

                 for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.text = json[i].optionName;
                    opt.value = json[i].optionValue;
                    $(target).options.add(opt);
                }
            }
    });
}
```